# Why I can't insert new row to Ext JS 4.2 Grid

Tags: extjs

Code definition added.

And here is store definition:

```
         Ext.define('MyTimesheet<?php echo $i; ?>.Store', {
            extend:'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'MyTimesheet<?php echo $i; ?>.Data',
            scroller by buffering 
            buffered: true, 
            leadingBufferZone: 150, 
            pageSize: 50,
            proxy: mytimesheetproxy<?php echo $i; ?>,
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                exception: function(reader, response, error, eOpts ) {
                    //var respObj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    if (respObj.success === false) {
                      //console.log(respObj.msg);
                      
                    }
                    //console.log('here!');
                },
                load: function (store, records, successful) {
                    ;
                    if (successful === false) {
                       
                    }
                }
           }
        });
```

Okay here is all asked code.

EDIT: Added a store definition asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-add) is the documentation of the **add** method of a store.
You should be able to add a new record without using the *Ext.ModelManager* as below:

```
myStore.add({some: 'data'});
```

Can you please post the Store definition please?

EDIT

[Here a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3j72) with a pretty easy example of a Model, Store and Grid with the "Add Row" functionality.

Comment: I added store definition.

Comment: Thanks, but what you posted is the model, not the store (note that you are extending Ext.data.Model). Keep it anyway in your question, but I need the store definition too (the one where you extend Ext.data.Store) for further analysis

Comment: Here I created a basic [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3j72) that shows you the Add Row functionality

Comment: It's working ok when grid is empty it can add rows. But if we add default single line for user to edit and want add button fill 2nd row to the grid your code not work. Default line added with JSON when grid loaded.

Comment: Please post your store definition, the one that extends Ext.data.Store, cause the one you posted is the model

Comment: I added now store definition.

Comment: Now I clearly see the problem! A buffered store doesnt support write operations (at least in that old ExtJs version if I remember correctly). So thats why you cant add a new record to it. Try removing buffered: true and leadingBufferZone config and give it another try. Sorry but now I am on mobile and cant test by myself

Answer (score 0):

We got it working. If we added default data with JSON it broke the Store row adder. So we defined default line with var data and used the var to generate first line and then adding more lines worked.